# How to reorder values across columns in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How can I reorder the values, in each column for each row in ascending order?

My DataFrame:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'date':  ['1/1/2021','1/1/2021','1/2/2021'],
                      'col1': [7,2,6],
                      'col2': [2,4,8],
                      'col3': [1,2,7]
                     })
print(data)

       date  col1  col2  col3
0  1/1/2021     7     2     1
1  1/1/2021     2     4     2
2  1/2/2021     6     8     7
```

However, I need to reorder the values in each row to be in ascending order, across the columns. So, the end result needs to look like;

```
       date  col1  col2  col3
0  1/1/2021     1     2     7
1  1/1/2021     2     2     4
2  1/2/2021     6     7     8
```

Comment: can you transpose, then sort each column increasing, then transpose again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.sort` along `axis=1` to sort the columns `col1`, `col2` and `col3` of the dataframe in the ascending order:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
data.loc[:, cols] = np.sort(data[cols], axis=1)
```

---

```
>>> data

       date  col1  col2  col3
0  1/1/2021     1     2     7
1  1/1/2021     2     2     4
2  1/2/2021     6     7     8
```

Answer (score 1):

you can `np.sort` and then `df.join`

```
data[['date']].join(pd.DataFrame(np.sort(data.drop('date',1),axis=1)).add_prefix('col'))
```

---

```
       date  col0  col1  col2
0  1/1/2021     1     2     7
1  1/1/2021     2     2     4
2  1/2/2021     6     7     8
```